# Node.js restarting every minute on OpsWorks amazon?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I use OpsWorks on AWS amazon. I have set node.js app on it and when I deploy it everything works as it should, however my main script (server.js) is being restarted exactly every minute. This is what code looks like:

```
var database = require('./database');
var config = require('./config.json')['development'];

console.log('started');

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) 
{        
    console.log(err);
});

foo();

function foo()
{   
    // some code
    setTimeout(foo, 2000);
}
```

Why do I get printed out "started" every minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpsWorks checks the health of your app every minute and restarts it the health check (HTTP GET) fails. The fact it is restarted every minute suggests that the health check is failing. Make sure your app listens to port 80.

The application must listen on port 80 (for HTTP requests) or port 443 (for HTTPS requests).

if you still have issues, make sure your app meets the conditions laid out in this doc: [Deploying Node.js Apps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinglayers-node.html)

Comment: And the status of health check if visible anywhere?